# There is no site URL in project properties. Where can I change it?

Tags: visual-studio, deployment

When trying to deploy a SharePoint app, the following error is shown:

> Error occurred in deployment step 'Uninstall app for SharePoint': Cannot connect to the SharePoint site: http://example.com/. Make sure that this is a valid URL and the SharePoint site is running on the local computer. If you moved this project to a new computer or if the URL of the SharePoint site has changed since you created the project, update the Site URL property of the project.

Unfortunately, when I go to the properties of the project (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>, or right-click on the project file in Solution Explorer, click on *Properties* in the context menu), there is no “Site URL” neither in SharePoint, nor in any other tab.

How can I change the site URL?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Select the project file in Solution Explorer and press <kbd>F4</kbd> (or *View*, *Properties Window*).

In the properties which appear in the new window, there is a Site URL:

[image: The screenshot of properties window]

Answer (score 1):

If you get the following message

> Remote SharePoint Site Connections Not Supported

add your URL in the host file in the folder C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc [image: host]

http://fdi-sharepoint.e-monsite.com/blog/sharepointcode/sharepointaddfoldertolistbycode.html

Comment: This link doesn't seem to be related to the content of this answer or question.